# Bioconductor package useR2013

Tags: r, installation, package, bioconductor

I cannot install package `useR2013`, I try all possible commands from bioconductor web site and nothing. All the time I get the same message from R. Can You give any tips?

output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
> install.packages("useR2013", repos=NULL, type="source")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘useR2013’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Bartek/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Ostrzeżenie: błędny pakiet 'useR2013'
BŁĄD: BŁĄD: nie określono pakietów
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Bartek\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" "useR2013"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘useR2013’ had non-zero exit status
```

OR

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> install.packages("useR2013")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘useR2013’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Bartek/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘useR2013’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

Comment: Please do not [crosspost](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2013-July/054082.html).  Did you do as [suggested](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2013-July/054085.html) and follow the directions at http://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2013/useR2013?  Are you still having problems?

Comment: How about
install.packages("useR2013_0.1.5.tar.gz", type="source", repos="null")
? Assuming you have downloaded the .tar.gz file from the link above and that you are running R in the directory where it can be found.